# Javascript is not working in Chrome and IE but working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

Here is the javacript code which is working perfectly in Mozilla but not working perfectly in IE and chrome.

```
function updateTable(tableID) 
{ 
    alert('inside the update'); 
    var arrayTemp=new Array();
    var str='';
    var arraycount=0;
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[4].childNodes[0];                
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {

           str+=  document.getElementById("flag"+i).value;
           str+=',';
           str+=  document.getElementById("Selected"+i).value;
           str+='`';




            } 

        }
        document.forms[0].updatearray.value=str;
        alert(' value is '+document.forms[0].updatearray.value);
        document.forms[0].submit();

        alert('Checkingdddddd');
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Here the forms is not getting submitted in IE and Chrome.Please tell is there any remedy for this.

I have tested and found that document.forms("formname").submit() is only working for chrome and IE but if I use document.forms["formname"].submit it is not working in chrome and IE  quite strange, a good advice from a great javascript magician is needed

Comment: What does it do in Chrome / IE?

Comment: Why are you calling `submit()` inside the loop?

Comment: Hello Jack the form is not getting submitted in chrome

Comment: @ Ates Goral the submit is not used inside the loop.

Comment: @Jack I am submittng the value present in the updatearray to a php controller where it will get updated in the database,It is updating perfectly in Mozilla but not in chrome as document.forms[0].submit doesn't submit the form.

Comment: @user1297878 There is a submit() fired every iteration of the loop as stated by Ates Goral - right after `str+='`';` ;)

Comment: @Andreas Yes I pasted the code wrongly document.forms[0].submit is used outside the code.When it is used outside the code it is not working still in chrome and firefox

Comment: See what error is there on console. Ctrl+Shift+J for Chrome.

Comment: it is working perfectly for   document.forms("userform").submit() It seems funny that it is working perfectly for this and also this is a type error

Comment: "type error" is still vague. Could you as well paste what the console says?

Comment: @pimvdb yes it is a type error document.forms("userform").submit() but is working perfectly in chrome compared to document.forms["userform"].submit() which is not working why it is like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the remedy  use   document.forms[0].submit as it supports in Mozilla , IE and Google chrome.

The answer is:

```
          Replace:

          document.forms[0].submit();

          To:

          document.forms[0].submit;
```